# How can I create nested root project in `nx` monorepo?

Tags: node.js, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I am using `nx` to manage a monorepo for `nodejs`. I have a folder structure like:

```
apps/frontend/ui
apps/frontend/design-system
apps/backend/service1
apps/backend/service2
```

There are 4 projects under `apps` folder. When I run `nx show projects`, all 4 will be returned. I am looking for a way to separate the `frontend` and `backend` projects. so if I run `nx` command from `apps` folder, it only lists two projects `frontend` and `backend`. But if run `nx` command inside `frontend` for example, it will give me `ui` and `design-system`.

Similarly, when I run `nx show projects --affected` under apps folder, I only want to see `frontend` or `backend` get returned rather than the sub projects underneath.

When I run `nx build frontend` under `apps` folder, it will trigger the build for `frontend` which will trigger the build for each projects under it.

Does `nx` support that kind of structure?